# How to check if an Auth'd Facebook user is the admin of a Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook Oauth2 Login with Laravel/PHP that I would like to behave differently if the user logging in is the admin of a Facebook page with a specific page ID.  Is there a way to do this with the FB API or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

`/me/accounts` gets you the pages the user have a role on and what role they have on that page. You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/accounts